# How to print to pdf with background images?

Tags: html, pdf, printing, adobe

I have installed the latest Adobe Pro and I'm only using "Adobe Pdf Printer". Now I´ve gotten an html page with some background images. When I print the HTML page then it does not include background images into the pdf. Im only using IE11

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good question.

In IE11, `Menu > Print > Page setup...`

You should check the `"Print Background Colors and Image".`

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

While being on the HTML page, click:
Print As.. > PDF > More Settings.. > >Options: Background graphics

[image: helpful screen]

Comment: I don't using chrome. Just IE11

Comment: Solving this problem in IE11 is very similiar, I can't see what made you so confused.

+don't use IE11..